# getting the hostname from a list of IPs in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a long list of IPs, but I need the hostnames of those servers, am trying to get every server with this command:

```
    dig +noall +answer -x <IP-address> | awk '{print $5}'
```

and i get the result, my question is how to automate this, I know it can be done, but I lack the skill to do it.

the file is called linux.hosts and the IPs are stacked as follows:

```
    <ip-address1>
    <ip-address2>
    <ip-address3>
    .
    .
    .
    <ip-address100>
```

am trying to create a script to automate the result of the command above and get output to another file

Update:

here is the code am using:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while read line; 
do
        dig +noall +noidnin +answer -x "$line" | awk '{print $5}'
        echo
done < linux.hosts > outputfile
```

the issue now will be how to identify the ones that are not resolving, not sure how to do that.

Comment: What part are you having trouble? Just read the file line by line into a variable, and run the `dig` command with the variable after `-x`.

Comment: Hi, I update the questions and specify the issue am having at the moment, basically will be how to validate if am getting result and if not how to past a string that says record not found or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Assign the result of `dig` to a variable, then you can check if the variable is empty.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
while read line
do
    host=$(dig +noall +noidnin +answer -x "$line" | awk '{print $5}')
    echo "$line ${host:-unknown}"
done < linux.hosts > outputfile
```

`${host:-unknown}` substitutes `unknown` in the expansion if the variable is empty.